# Is it better to use table or materialized view in creating another view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatable

I have a materialized view that uses datamart table. The materialized view was used for dashboard purposes but now decided to create another materialized view to create a more complex logic. I wanted to know if performance wise does using materialized view as a source would have a big impact to its performance compared to using the source table?

```
**Source Table**
create table if not exists table_datamart
( column int) ;

**Source Table View**
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS view_table_datamart
AS
 SELECT column from table_datamart
WITH DATA;

**New view with logic**
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS view_table_datamart_logic
AS
 SELECT column from view_table_datamart
WITH DATA;
```

Please note that I'm also using indexes on each table and views

Comment: You can't refresh the second materialized view when the first one hasn't been refreshed. At least it doesn't make sense. This does create additional lag between getting the data into your data mart, and extracting the information from the data mart. Personally I would try to avoid this.